# Have X-Ray trace ID, but searching using X-Ray console says "Data not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

On of my API Gateway logs entries indicates a timeout and I'm investigating where it's coming from. The log entry has an X-Ray trace ID but when I use X-Ray to search for it, I get "Data not found".

I'm expecting at least one node, the APIG , to show up in X-Ray. What am I missing?

**API Gateway CloudWatch Logs Insights I cannot find trace for**

query-string:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like "92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44"
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

| @timestamp | @message |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-12 23:19:52.559 | (92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44) X-ray Tracing ID : Root=1-60270cfb-2e033ce35d226f3f1fc240b0 |
| 2021-02-12 23:19:52.558 | (92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44) Execution failed due to a timeout error |
| 2021-02-12 23:19:52.558 | (92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44) Gateway response type: DEFAULT_5XX with status code: 504 |
| 2021-02-12 23:19:52.558 | (92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44) Method completed with status: 504 |
| 2021-02-12 23:19:23.558 | (92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44) API Key authorized because method 'GET /shifts' does not require API Key. Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits |
| 2021-02-12 23:19:23.558 | (92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44) Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage eejmp2ziyc/prod |
| 2021-02-12 23:19:23.558 | (92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44) Starting execution for request: 92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44 |
| 2021-02-12 23:19:23.558 | (92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44) HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /shifts |
| 2021-02-12 23:19:23.557 | (92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44) Verifying Usage Plan for request: 92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44. API Key: API Stage: eejmp2ziyc/prod |
| 2021-02-12 23:19:23.556 | (92300847-04fd-4969-8728-92d12887ee44) Extended Request Id: ap73UGVmPHcFX1g= |

**Api Gateway CloudWatch Logs Insights I can find trace for**

query-string:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter @message like "b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1"
```

| @timestamp | @message |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-17 07:15:23.939 | (b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1) Successfully completed execution |
| 2021-02-17 07:15:23.939 | (b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1) Method completed with status: 200 |
| 2021-02-17 07:15:23.939 | (b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1) AWS Integration Endpoint RequestId : 9686fa9d-262d-41e9-bd3f-b261ad06297a |
| 2021-02-17 07:15:23.939 | (b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1) X-ray Tracing ID : Root=1-602cc28a-5b6bd5b11e2a02235a292a15 |
| 2021-02-17 07:15:22.457 | (b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1) Starting execution for request: b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1 |
| 2021-02-17 07:15:22.457 | (b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1) HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /scheduleSummary |
| 2021-02-17 07:15:22.456 | (b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1) API Key authorized because method 'GET /scheduleSummary' does not require API Key. Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits |
| 2021-02-17 07:15:22.456 | (b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1) Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage eejmp2ziyc/prod |
| 2021-02-17 07:15:22.454 | (b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1) Verifying Usage Plan for request: b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1. API Key: API Stage: eejmp2ziyc/prod |
| 2021-02-17 07:15:22.453 | (b80e4922-7f18-4024-8f9a-fadba068f0c1) Extended Request Id: a4NVpGGIPHcFevg= |

**X-Ray**

[image]

Comment: you have checked `Enable X-Ray Tracing` on Api Gateway Stage?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala, yes it is enabled. Otherwise that trace ID would not have shown up in the APIG logs ...

Comment: ok. is it just this timed out request that is missing in X-Ray or everything?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala X-Ray is showing traces and has data, it's specifically this one that I cannot find. Unfortunately there's no easy way for me to tell if any other traces are "missing"

Comment: It is possible that this trace did not get sampled and therefore was not recorded by XRay. Can you find the logs for a trace which was sampled and paste it here so that we can compare if the `X-ray Tracing ID` looks any different for it?

Comment: @PrashantSrivastava I've updated the question with an example of a trace I can find. Regarding the sampling, how does that work? I assumed any log entries with a X-ray id means it is part of the sample, no? To be honest I could not find any documentation to explain if having a trace ID means you are part of the sample or not but I assumed it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised a support case with AWS to ask about this. Their response was:

> It looks like X-Ray had some segment loss around that time-frame which could have been the reason for the missing traces. Trace loss should be expected sometimes. X-Ray doesn't charge the customer for any traces which were not stored.

Answer (score 0):

Having trace ID doesn't mean that get sampled.

Trace Id is only one part of Trace Header. For example look at this:

```
X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-5759e988-bd862e3fe1be46a994272793;Sampled=0
```

As you see we have traceID but Samples is off (Sampled=0)

To find out if your trace get sampled or not you need to look at `X-Amzn-Trace-Id`

You can find more in here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-concepts.html#xray-concepts-tracingheader

Default sampling is 5%, if you want to use it for all or more requests, you can change sampling:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-sampling.html